# How to get different table's on same page

Tags: php, html, sql, html-table

What I would like to do is as following : 
I have 3 table's with data from an sql database.(just an simple SQL query).

SQL:

```
"SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE employee = '"  . $name. "'
```

I also have an form where I can select an option that then goes into the SQL query

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

    echo "<option value = " . ($row['name']) . ">". $row['name'] ." </option>";
}

echo '  </select>';
echo '  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">';
echo '</form>';
```

With the form I use an simple `GET` to get the form output and put it in the SQL query. Now the problem is that I have 3 tables that almost do the same but i would like to have 3 forms where I can give input and then where I give my input that table shows. Is this possible ? And are there any examples.

Comment: `mysql_*` is officially [**deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). You need to change to prepared statments. See [this post for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: It's possible.try it

Comment: This code does work at the moment with mysql but I am trying to add some code so that the tables only show when I give input in my form. So the problem is not with the connection

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*only show when I give input in my form*"? Can you explain your question better?

Comment: I would like to have 3 buttons and 3 drop downs and when I choose one of the options and then press the button  the page will refresh and return 1 table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment mysql_* is depreciated, you need to use mysqli or PDO.
Using mysqli your code should be like this

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
//use your host name, mysql user name, mysql password and your database name in place of "localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db"
$sql ="SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE employee = '"  . $name. "'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo "<option value = " . ($row['name']) . ">". $row['name'] ." </option>";
}
```

The simple solution for your problem is to make action page of all your three forms to same and use if statements to use the different queries for different input eg:

```
if(isset($_GET['name'])){
 $sql ="query1";
} elseif(isset($_GET['yourSecondOption'])){
 $sql ="query1";
}elseif(isset($_GET['yourThirdOption'])){ 
$sql ="query3";
}
```

Comment: While very true that `mysql_*` is old and outated, and that `mysqli_*` is better - this does in no way solve OP's question - you also did not say anything about *prepared statements* - so his code is still vulnerable to SQL-injection!

Comment: I am aware of the old metod that I use but I think that is not the problem in my code.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Thank you so much for you're answer. It helped me very much. And I changed the mysql content to PDO